# QGZ file without any non-ASCII characters opens just as a completely blank project

Tags: qgis, corrupt, qgz

I just wanted to open a qgz project file which I used one week before in QGIS 3.6.1 without any problems. Today it opens just as a blank project like a new empty one (same problem in 3.8.3 as well as in the long stable version).

But it should still work since it has 61 KB.

I read about the same problem on this page

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Sometimes-qgz-files-opens-just-as-a-completely-blank-project-td5389126.html

... but it cannot be an ASCII problem since the name of the file is "Resource-based Dependency in Tropical Societies". Saving as a new file doesn't work and unzipping either. Is there any known solution?

Elsewhere it was considered as solved with version 3.6, but obviously it is not.